# ThreeJS animation not running in Typescript Eslint5 Next Application

Tags: typescript, next.js, three.js, eslint, typescript2.0

I have a typesafe typescript application running on next and need to implement an "old" three.js animation I built for a react project. Since typescript is a bit tricky with getting document elements i tried the following but to no surprise i keep failing at my attemts to make it work. Can anyone help?
Home and AnimateCube are TSX files but Animate3D is JSX.

Here are the three scripts:

**Home.tsx**

```js
import { Box, Heading } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { ThreeSphere} from 'components/elements/Animate3D';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Heading size="md" marginBottom={6} textAlign={'center'}>
        Welcome!
      </Heading>
      <Heading size="sm" marginBottom={3} textAlign={'center'}>
        Merging Centralized and DeCentralized Finance..
      </Heading>
      <Heading size="sm" marginBottom={8} textAlign={'center'}>
        Please connect your wallet to see your Blockchain Interactions
      </Heading>

      <Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'center'}>
        <ThreeSphere/>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**AnimateCube.tsx**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Animate3D from './Animate3D.jsx';
import { Box } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const AnimateCube = () => {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState();

  return (
    <Box className="cube" minH="260px" minW="260px" boxSize="100%" objectFit="fill" onLoad={() => setIsLoaded}>
      {isLoaded ? <Animate3D /> : 'Cube should be here!'}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default AnimateCube;
```

**And ThreeSphere.jsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
class ThreeSphere extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const width = this.mount.clientWidth;
    const height = this.mount.clientHeight;
    //ADD SCENE
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //ADD CAMERA
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
    this.camera.position.z = 4;
    //ADD RENDERER
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0);
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    //ADD sphere
    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 8, 18);
    const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
      color: 0x3ef5f5,
      wireframe: true,
    });
    this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(this.sphere);
    this.start();
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.stop();
    this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  }
  start = () => {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    }
  };
  stop = () => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
  };
  animate = () => {
    this.sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
    this.sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
    this.renderScene();
    this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  };
  renderScene = () => {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ width: "300px", height: "300px" }}
        ref={(mount) => {
          this.mount = mount;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default ThreeSphere;
```

I tried making the jsx file typescript typesafe but every time I end up with document not defined even when seting type <HTMLDivElemen. . . The animation should render a spheare only made up of rainbow colored lines.

Tried

```
// Check if "document" exists before using it
 if (typeof document === 'undefined') {
   return null;
 }
```

Tried this now but get too many linting errors I don't understand:
I now tried making it typescript like this but my skills fall short on all the new Linting rules - HTMLDivElement - this. - width/height - and the request/cancelAnimatioFrame throws error:

tsx file:

```js
    import React, { Component, RefObject } from 'react';
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    
    interface Props {}
    interface State {}
    
    class ThreeSphere extends Component<Props, State> {
      private mount: RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | undefined;
      private scene!: THREE.Scene;
      private camera!: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
      private renderer!: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
      private sphere!: THREE.Mesh;
      private frameId!: number;
    
      componentDidMount() {
        const width = this.mount.current?.clientWidth;
        const height = this.mount.current?.clientHeight;
        //ADD SCENE
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        //ADD CAMERA
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
        this.camera.position.z = 4;
        //ADD RENDERER
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
        this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0);
        this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
        this.mount.current?.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        //ADD SPHERE
        const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 8, 18);
        const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
          color: 0x3ef5f5,
          wireframe: true,
        });
        this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        this.scene.add(this.sphere);
        this.start();
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.stop();
        this.mount.current!.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
      }
      start = () => {
        if (!this.frameId) {
          this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        }
      };
      stop = () => {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
      };
      animate = () => {
        this.sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
        this.sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
        this.renderScene();
        this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
      };
      renderScene = () => {
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <div
            style={{ width: '300px', height: '300px' }}
            ref={(mount) => {
              this.mount = mount;
            }}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default ThreeSphere;
```

Comment: I now tried making it typescript like this but my skills fall short on all the new Linting rules - this. - width/height - and the request/cancelAnimatioFrame throws error:

tsx file:

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error was that React rendered the component too fast for the animation to render the scene and thus the animation sees the component as Unmounted and stops the animation.
I fixed it by removing this.stop in componentWillUnmount and just remove the stop function. The component now renders the animation twice but removes the first animationFrame from start function. So now it works.